# VBA code - Stuck at the 4th loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, internet-explorer-11

I have a code that is supposed to open a website, select a location, copy the HTML table to the Excel sheet and repeat on another location. However when I tried running the 'For' loop, I got error at the 4th iteration. The message said "Object variable or With block variable not set". The debug tool pointed at line 44

```
Sub ParseTable()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Document object
    Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
    Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
    Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
    Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements
    Dim ieURL As String 'URL
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As String

y = "A1"

For x = 1 To 4
    If x <> 2 Then 'Skip iteration 2
        Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ieURL = "***"
        IE.navigate ieURL
 'Wait
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set htmldoc = IE.document 'Document webpage

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    IE.document.getElementById("ddlLevel1").selectedIndex = x
    IE.document.getElementById("ddlLevel1").FireEvent ("onchange")
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set eleColtr = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags

    'This section populates Excel
            i = 0 'start with first value in tr collection
            For Each eleRow In eleColtr 'for each element in the tr collection
                Set eleColtd = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
                j = 0 'start with the first value in the td collection
                For Each eleCol In eleColtd 'for each element in the td collection
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(y).Offset(i, j).Value = eleCol.innerText 'paste the inner text of the td element, and offset at the same time
                    j = j + 1 'move to next element in td collection
                Next eleCol 'rinse and repeat
                i = i + 1 'move to next element in td collection
            Next eleRow 'rinse and repeat
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(y).Offset(i, 0).Select
            y = "A" & ActiveCell.Row
            IE.Quit
      End If
 Next x
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Not sure what could be the possible cause. I did get the tables from first 4 locations (minus location 2) on my Excel sheet. Pardon for my long, inefficient code (I am not a programmer myself). The webpage that I use requires login and has confidential data, but I will try to provide input as much as possible. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Line 44 says `j = 0`.  Is that correct?

Comment: I guess the error is here: `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")`. Probably you are trying to get the "td"s inside this "tr", but the "tr" itself is Nothing at some point. To be sure you should stop your execution right before the error happens and analyse the variables.

Comment: Some other possibilities are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5szkzs17.aspx)

Comment: Yes @mathiasfk that is the line. Trying to figure out a way to analyse the  variables as  you said. Any suggestion?

Comment: @LeslieHeng well you can add the variables to the watch and run your code step by step or add a breakpoint on the problematic line, not sure if you are familiar with that... if not please take a look, it helps a lot

Comment: @mathiasfk will read on that. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this happen in a lot of examples that try to wait for `IE.Busy` before processing further. The problem is that the document model hasn't quite formed yet so you get an error trying to access the element in the object model.

The safest way is to actually loop until the object exists - ie. if you know for a fact that it will appear in each document. If you want to play safe, you can add a limit on the number of checks you do before you stop with an error message.

Add this to top of your module

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Then replace this line (if it's the problem line)

```
Set eleColtr = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

With this slight Delay and DoEvents - then a loop to check for your tr elements

```
DoEvents
Sleep 1000 ' delay once second
Do 
   DoEvents
   Sleep 500 ' delay half a second
Loop Until not IsNull(IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr"))
```

If it goes into an endless loop, not finding your tr elements, you can put a counter on number of tries

I'd also add a delay at the start of each loop

After `For Each eleRow In eleColtr`
add `Sleep 500`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I amended the code accordingly, but I get infinite loop at 2nd loop even after i put a counter in the loop section of the code. 'Do
            DoEvents
            counter = counter + 1
            Sleep 500
        Loop Until IsNull(ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")) Or counter < 2'. Is this not correct?

Comment: `Do    DoEvents    counter = counter + 1    Sleep 500    Loop Until IsNull(ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")) Or counter < 5` Amended for formatting

Comment: Edited loop. Should be NOT ISNULL

Comment: Great to hear. Please take time to mark it as an answer or upvote it if you found it useful